# SQL Server: SUM of a column based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity
--------------------------------------------
     1           10248     11          12
     2           10248     42          10
     3           10248     72           5
     4           10249     14           9
     5           10249     51          40
```

I need to get the total quantity based on the `OrderID`. So ideally the result should look like:

```
OrderID Quantity
----------------
10248      27
10249      49
```

I guess I have to group it by `OrderID` but not sure how to get the sum of quantity based on the `OrderID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using:

```
select OrderId, sum(Quantity) from yourtable group by OrderId
```

That should do it.

Comment: Tried it but for some reason did not work(No Syntax Error), but now when I copy and paste your code works perfect. Facepalm!!!